# Jest testing the event target that was collected onClick

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am testing that `myFunction` is called when a button is clicked. `myFunction` actually just calls another function and passes some stuff to it, including **the element that was clicked**, which I expect to actually be the `img` inside the button.

E.g:

```
<button class="button" onClick=myFunction(someArgs)>
   <img class="imageInsideButton" />
/>

  myFunction = (someArgs) => (event) => 
    this.props.someOtherFunction(
      someArgs
      event.target
    );
```

In my test I am trying to check that `someOtherFunction` was called with the expected args, which includes `event.target`

```
  function render(args, renderer = shallow) {
    const component = renderer(<MyComponent {...args} />);

    return {
      component,
      buttons: () => component.find(".button"),
      imagesInsideButtons: () => component.find(".imageInsideButton"),
    };
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    myProps = {
      myFunction: jest.fn(),
    };
  });

  it("Should call someOtherFunction with the correct args", () => {
     const { buttons, imagesInsideButtons } = render(defaultArgs, mount);
     const indexClicked = 1;

     buttons().at(indexClicked).simulate("click");

     expect(myProps.someOtherFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
         someArgs, imagesInsideButtons().at(indexClicked)
     );
  });
```

So in this test I am simulating a click of one of the `buttons()` (in this case the second one listed). I'm expecting the event target that was clicked to be the `img` that was wrapped inside this button.

This does sort of work, but the problem appears to be that my test expects a `ReactComponent` but instead gets an actual node:

**Expected**

the other args,
ReactWrapper {}

**Received**

the other args,
`<button class="button"><img class"imageInsideButton" /></button>`

It seems like the result is sort of OK, in terms of getting this event target, but the way in which I have written the test means these are not matching. How do I make this test work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [simulating the click](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html), you could pass a fake target, and expect THAT target.

`buttons().at(indexClicked).simulate("click", { target: 999 });`

```js
// test
expect(myProps.someOtherFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  someArgs, 999
);
```